# impress.js with fixed top nav not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, impress.js

I have been working with impress.js, html5 and css. I have got my impress.js presentation to a standard I am quite happy with but I am trying to implement a fixed top nav similar to Twitters.

The current implementation does not work correctly. if you click the bar whilst on a slide/step the links are unclickable.

[My Attempt](http://www.fyldetrade.co.uk/v2/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

    <title>PATCHU_</title>

    <meta name="author" content="patchu" />

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:regular,semibold,italic,italicsemibold|PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic|PT+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
</head>

<body class="impress-not-supported">
<div class="fallback-message">
    <p>Your browser <strong>doesn't support the features required</strong> by my website, so you are presented with a simplified version.</p>
    <p>For the best experience please use the latest <strong>Chrome</strong>, <strong>Safari</strong> or <strong>Firefox</strong> browser.</p>
</div>
<div class="navbar-fixed-top2" align="center">
<p>Navigation will go here <a class="" href="#websites" title="My Websites">My Websites</a> 
<a class="" href="#about" title="My Websites">About</a> 
<a class="" href="#contact" title="My Websites">Contact</a>
<a class="" href="#applications" title="My Websites">Applications</a>
</div>
<div id="impress" data-transition-duration="800">   
    <div id="title" class="step slide" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-scale="3">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>@PATCHU_</h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="step slide" data-x="-1000" data-y="-700" data-rotate="270" data-scale="5">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="about1" class="step slide about" data-x="-1900" data-y="880" data-z="-100" data-rotate="270" data-scale="1">
            <p>Apart from making <strong>awesome websites</strong>, I love computer networking and making <strong>iOS applications.</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div id="about2" class="step slide about" data-x="-1900" data-y="100" data-z="-100" data-rotate="270" data-scale="1">
            <p>Minimalist, <strong>Perfectionist</strong>, Gamer and Apple fanboy. I have a passion for creating stuff. Love trying out <strong>new technologies</strong> and experiences.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about3" class="step slide about" data-x="-1900" data-y="-800" data-z="-100" data-rotate="270" data-scale="1">
            <p>I mostly code in <strong>PHP</strong> and <strong>Objective-C</strong>, but I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about4" class="step slide about" data-x="-1900" data-y="-1600" data-z="-100" data-rotate="270" data-scale="1">
            <p><strong>Graduated</strong> with a <strong>1:1</strong> (84% Average) in Computer Network Technology BSc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="websites" class="step slide" data-x="7100" data-y="-700" data-z="-3000" data-rotate="0" data-scale="5">
            <h1>Websites</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="applications" class="step slide application" data-x="3950" data-y="-4500" data-z="-3000" data-rotate="90" data-scale="5">
            <h1>Applications</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="step slide" data-x="-180" data-y="2100" data-scale="3">
            <h1>Connect</h1>
            <p></p>

            <div id="contact_images">
                <a href=""><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
                <a href=""><img src="images/linkedin.png"></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script>
    //All hail megatron
    impress().init();
    //impress().showMenu();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
    Resetting the humans
*/
.navbar-fixed-top2{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:3000;
}
```

Comment: Whether it will effect your problem or not, you should also have left: 0px; or the like in your .navbar styles.

Answer (score 10):

This is due to a work-around for a chrome bug in impress.js, see the comments at the end of the CSS file that ships with it.

To make the links in your navbar clickable, add the following to your .navbar-fixed-top2 CSS class:

```
pointer-events: auto
```

Alternatively, add the following class to your CSS:

```
.extra-clickable { pointer-events: auto }
```

... and then add that class to anything outside of #impress that you want to have clickable.